# Missing run button and use dropdown from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

I have somehow lost the run button on my toolbar, along with the dropdown to select what database I am running my script against.  I now have to work with a remote Azure database and would really like having that dropdown showing what context I am in.

This is what my toolbar currently looks like
[image: Toolbar]

I have tried Windows->Reset Window Layout and I tried clicking arrow at the far right of the toolbar->Add or Remove Buttons->Reset Toolbar, but neither of these seem to restore what I am missing.

How can I get back my run button and the Database selector dropdown to select what my script is running against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow those steps

```
View -> Toolbars -> [choose] SQL Editor
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This was really annoying me lol.

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak No problem glad to help